# haproxy reverse ssl termination

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy

How can I achieve *reverse SSL termination* with ha proxy?
From my backend via HAproxy I need to a https enabled web service. How can I successfully proxy all traffic to that service via HAProxy?

Below results in `Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.`

```
frontend foofront
    bind 127.0.0.1:443
    mode tcp
    default_backend foo

backend fooback
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    server foo foo.bar.com:443  check
```

Comment: Is your certificate valid, i.e. does it matche the supplied domain name? Is it self-signed? You can disable verification by addind `ssl verify none` to `server` line, but this is, of course, dangerous.

Comment: The ssl certificate is provided by the external web service. Connecting without the proxy works just fine.

Comment: The error you mentioned, it's produced by client, correct? Since the downstream servers handle actual traffic, their certificates must be issued for the domain you're accessing (e.g. `curl https://locahost:443` won't work as domain does not match). I'll write more detailed answer with available options.

Comment: Correct. This is my problem.

Answer (score 4):

With HAProxy you usually have two options for handling TLS-related scenarios. `TLS Passthrough` and `TLS Termination`.

### TLS Passthrough

Looks like you're trying to do this in the example you gave.

In this mode, `HAProxy` does not touch traffic in any way, but is just forwarding it to the backend. When TLS is involved, that means that the backend has to have a proper certificate for a domain it's accessed from - if your `HAProxy` is handling traffic for `myexample.com`, backend servers will need to have appropriate certificates for `myexample.com` installed.

You can always check which certificate is served by using `openssl s_client`:

`openssl s_client -connect localhost:443`

### TLS Termination

Alternatively, you can terminate TLS traffic on `HAProxy` itself. This will allow you to use any backend (both encrypted and unencrypted). In this case, `HAProxy` itself decrypts traffic for `myexample.com` and forwards it to backend.

In your case, configuration would look something like:

```
frontend foofront
    bind 127.0.0.1:80
    bind 127.0.0.1:443 ssl crt /path/to/cert/for/myexample.com
    mode tcp
    default_backend foo

backend foo
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    server foo foo.bar.com:443 check ssl verify none # or verify all to enforce ssl checking
```

You can find more info on both approaches [here](https://serversforhackers.com/c/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But is it also possible to serve the frontend as plain http, have the client call the frontend via `curl localhost:<<myFrontendPort>>` and then have the backend talk via https to the external web service? Your solution would require to manually keep the certificate of the external web service up to date.

Comment: I've added binding for port 80 in TLS Termination case, that should work. I don't know the nuances of your setup so it might be a bit different for you, but you can mix and match both approaches depending on what you actually need.